# APN Settings Android

Tags: android, settings, apn

I want to be able to send custom APN settings to an android device via the use of a server or sms or e-mail or any other means. I want the settings to be added as a new APN profile on the phone (via the user permission on device) Is it possible to send a type of a file with the XML settings for the APN profile?  This solution cannot use an external app so I am wondering if this is possible or if there are some kind of other ideas that someone can give me to send APN settings (rather than instruction set on how to add them)

Regards,
Bart

Comment: Have you found any solution?